# WooCommerce, auto-process orders on payment not working

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-ipn

I have added this piece of code to my functions file, but the order is still not being marked as "processed" after the payment is made.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'my_change_status_function');
function my_change_status_function($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    mail('xxx@xxx.com','payment','received');
    return 'completed';
}
```

The IPN is correctly setup on MercadoPago (the gateway we are using) and on the access log, we can see that MP is actually sending the ping to the server for this. If you try to access the ipn url, you will see a `1` as content.

Any idea on what might be happening? The mail sentence is just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to put

```
$order->payment_complete();
```

or if failed

```
$order->update_status( 'failed', sprintf( __( 'Payment %s via IPN.', 'woocommerce' ), "failed" ) );
```

Is

```
return 'completed';
```

doing anything?